# Trouble merging object with getters / setters

Tags: javascript

I'm facing some problems with merging two objects with property getters / setters which degrade into values. How to prevent that ? Do i have to clone its manually ?

Below, a contrived example of my pb :

```js
function Factory1() {
  const p = {};

  return {
    get prop1 () { return p.prop; },
    set prop1 (value) { p.prop = value; }
  };
}

function Factory2() {
  const p = {};

  return {
    get prop2 () { return p.prop; },
    set prop2 (value) { p.prop = value; }
  }
}


const obj1 = Factory1();
const obj2 = Factory2();

const obj3a = {...Factory1(), ...Factory2()};
const obj3b = Object.assign(Factory1(), Factory2());

console.log('obj1.prop1 =>', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj1, 'prop1'));
console.log('obj2.prop2 =>', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj2, 'prop2'));

console.log('spread prop1 =>', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj3a, 'prop1'));
console.log('spread prop2 =>', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj3a, 'prop2'));
console.log('assign prop1 =>', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj3b, 'prop1'));
console.log('assign prop2 =>', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj3b, 'prop2'));
```

---

### Update 2018-10-11

A simpler example :

```js
function Factory1() {
  return {
    get prop1 () { return 42; }
  };
}

const obj1 = Factory1();
const obj2 = Object.assign({}, Factory1())

console.log('obj1.prop1 =>', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj1, 'prop1'));
// result
// obj1.prop1 => { get: [Function],
//   set: undefined,
//   enumerable: true,
//   configurable: true }

console.log('obj2.prop1 =>', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj2, 'prop1'));
// result
// obj2.prop1 => { value: 42,
//   writable: true,
//   enumerable: true,
//   configurable: true }
```

---

### A more real example

On request, i'll try to illustrate what type of code i'm facing. Of course, this is a concatenation of code extract dispatched in multiple module.

```
import axios from 'axios';

function createAxios (options = {}) {
  const axiosClient = axios.create(options);
  axiosClient.defaults.withCredentials = false;
  axiosClient.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'text/html';

  return {axiosClient};
}

function WithQuery ({axiosClient}) {
  // This is a sample server that supports CORS.
  var sampleUrl = 'http://html5rocks-cors.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/index.html';  

  return {
    query (url) {
      return axiosClient.get(url || sampleUrl);
    }
  };
}

function WithLastModified (context) {
  let lastModified;

  context.axiosClient.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    const {headers} = response;
    console.log('header last-modified:', headers['last-modified']);
    lastModified = headers['last-modified'];
    return response;
  });

  return {
    getLastModified () {
      return lastModified;
    },
    get lastModified () {
      return lastModified;
    }
  }
}

function build (options) {
  const httpClient = createAxios(options);
  return Object.assign({},
    httpClient,
    {search: WithQuery(httpClient)},
    WithLastModified(httpClient));
}

const api = build();
api.search.query().then(() => {
  console.log('get lastModified:', api.lastModified); // not working, always undefined
  console.log('getLastModified:', api.getLastModified()); // work
});
```

This type of factory methods is used to inject dependencies and add functionality through pseudo-mixins to a final object.

Comment: What exactly is your use case? If you don't want to share the private `p` object, then yes you will have to make a manual clone method.

Comment: Possible workarounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47952443/3661587)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check your code you'll notice that even getting the descriptors and adding them to a new object, your accessors will hold access to the `factoryN` inner scope's `p` object (those accessors form closures).

That is, you're going to mutate the same target object even when you define new descriptors into new object instances.

Conclusion: if you don't rephrase your question to explain what's your actual goal, I would say that there's no way to solve the problem.

### Answer to some OP's comment

> I'm not sure i understand your statement on distinct local variable p defined on 2 distinct closures. My concern is about obj1.prop1 and obj2.prop2 get / set turned into simple value on obj3a

Take your own code:

```
function Factory1() {
  // This is a function scoped reference
  const p = {};

  return {
    get prop1 () { return p.prop; }, 
    set prop1 (value) { p.prop = value; }
  };
}
```

`p` is a function scoped reference, and the whole returned accessors are closures which capture `p`.

If you take these accessors and you add them to another object, `p` will still point to the captured reference. Thus, when you set `prop1` in many objects, all of them will set the same target `p` object!

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your statement on distinct local variable `p` defined on 2 distinct closures.
My concern is about `obj1.prop1` and `obj2.prop2` get / set turned into simple _value_ on `obj3a`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your clarification, i see your point.
However, my sample code is a _contrived_ example, and my concern is about get / set handling when merging objects.

Comment: @Sté It's not a *contrived example* It seems to be a *bad example*. I suggest you that the question should be completely rephrased to explain you actual use case. If the *contrived example* mimics your actual case, then there's no solution. Either way, I doubt that copying accessors may be a good idea.

Comment: @Sté About the behavior, there's no mistery: you won't automatically copy accessors when cloning objects unless you implement some custom function to do so using `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`... But you'll find troubles with accessors since they might be closures as I've already demonstrated you in my answer...

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my sample. What you mean is that you discourage merging objects with accessors, don't you?
So, how to assemble multiple _mixins_ to make a usable object, can you share some tips?

Comment: @Sté I still don't see the actual case. You should explain your actual goal: what are you trying to solve in your project?

Comment: I've a fair amount of code which was rewritten from `function  getXXX ()` to accessor `get XXX ()` without measuring impact when used in conjunction with `Object.assign` (or spread syntax). I would like to find the best solution, knowing that i've only access to the `Object.assign`part.

Comment: @Sté You should be able to explain your goal. Try to summarize it. It should be possible! :D

Comment: @Sté Probably there's another approach to solve your requirement. If you explain the whole requirement, one might be ale to give you a solution without guessing too much...

Comment: @Sté I see. So you're implementing some sort of DI using closures and mixins. Then, I believe that copying descriptors would work

Comment: So, i will implement (or find a library with) an _assign like_ function which specifically take care of descriptors. Thanks you @MatíasFidemraizer.

Comment: @Sté It should be an easy one!